How to hide "/" character delimiter in total time when using the native audio player in Chromium using CSS only?
I'm styling a native browser element, <audio>, and to do so, it's necessary to work with native browser pseudo elements, such as:
.audio-message audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
        display: none;
}


Hiding this element makes the total audio duration element appear with a "/" in front.

I wish to hide this slash, as it makes no sense in the context where the remaining time is hidden, but I cannot use :first-letter with native element selectors.
My question is, how can we apply something like:
.audio-message audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display::first-letter {
    display: none;  
}

The example doesn't work, I tried :is(), using :first-letter instead of ::, and also changing to hover and adding important to test if the issue was the selector.
I'd rather a CSS only solution, I know it could be done in JS in a way or other, but there are several audio elements and it would hurt performance.


audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display  {
    display: none;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display::first-letter {
    /* Doesn't work */
    display: none;  
}
<audio controls="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg"></audio>



Test the snippet using Chrome-based browser please.

@Paulie_D thank you for the instruction, snippet provided

Thanks for including code, but please make a snippet that has a source so we can easily see the problem.

thank you for the suggestion @AHaworth
Done

There is not likely to be a cross-browser solution to this. Wouldn’t it make more sense to create your own custom player?

As this can't be achieved using pseudo elements as suggested in the title, you may like to rewrite the title in a way which doesn't restrict the technology to be used in a solution.

@AHaworth is it really impossible? Can you provide some evidence? I saw that the "User Agent Stylesheet" in Chromium applies CSS to shadow root. Maybe there is a CSS property that might hide the first letter or make its font size zero without using the ::first-letter? Or maybe a selector using [pseudo="..."], anyways, the reason why I'm restricting the tech is that JS is not scalable for too many audios (i.e.: A conversation), also there are already answers and questions on how to create it using JS. For me it's more acceptable to have an extra "/" than lagging and having users frustrated

The audio player is displayed differently in every browser. We could only address each of them with cumbersome coding, thus it's a better approach to create a custom audio player, like this for example:


// scripts.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  var playPauseButton = document.getElementById('play-pause');
  var playIcon = document.getElementById('play-icon');
  var pauseIcon = document.getElementById('pause-icon');
  var volumeControl = document.getElementById('volume');
  var muteButton = document.getElementById('mute');
  var speakerIcon = document.getElementById('speaker-icon');
  var muteIcon = document.getElementById('mute-icon');
  var speedOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.speed-option');
  var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var currentTimeDisplay = document.getElementById('current-time');

  // Play/Pause functionality
  playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      playIcon.style.display = 'none';
      pauseIcon.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      playIcon.style.display = 'block';
      pauseIcon.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
  // Revert to play icon when audio ends
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    playIcon.style.display = 'block';
    pauseIcon.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // Volume control functionality
  volumeControl.addEventListener('input', function() {
    audio.volume = volumeControl.value;
    if (audio.volume === 0) {
      speakerIcon.style.display = 'none';
      muteIcon.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      speakerIcon.style.display = 'block';
      muteIcon.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  // Mute functionality
  muteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (audio.muted) {
      audio.muted = false;
      speakerIcon.style.display = 'block';
      muteIcon.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      audio.muted = true;
      speakerIcon.style.display = 'none';
      muteIcon.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });

  // Playback speed control functionality
  speedOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener('click', function() {
      audio.playbackRate = this.dataset.speed;
    });
  });

  // Update current time display and timeline
  audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    var currentMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
    var currentSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime % 60);
    if (currentSeconds < 10) {
      currentSeconds = '0' + currentSeconds;
    }
    currentTimeDisplay.textContent = currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds;

    // Update timeline
    var value = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
    timeline.value = value;
  });

  // Seek functionality for timeline
  timeline.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var time = (timeline.value / 100) * audio.duration;
    audio.currentTime = time;
  });
});
/* styles.css */
.audio-player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  z-index: 37;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#play-pause {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#play-pause:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 100px;
}

#timeline {
  width: 80px;
}

.volume-control {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.volume-control input[type="range"] {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 47px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}

.volume-control:hover .wrap {
  overflow: visible;
}

#play-icon,
#pause-icon,
#speaker-icon,
#mute-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content button {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown-content button:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.wrap::before {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 43px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: -17px;
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #595959;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

input[type="range"]:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* For IE */
input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Custom Audio Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="audio-player">
    <audio id="audio" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg"></audio>
    <button id="play-pause">
            <svg id="play-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M8 5v14l11-7L8 5z" fill="currentColor"/>
            </svg>
            <svg id="pause-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
                <path d="M6 19h4V5H6v14zm8-14v14h4V5h-4z" fill="currentColor"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
    <span id="current-time">0:00</span>
    <input type="range" id="timeline" value="0" max="100">
    <div class="volume-control">
      <button id="mute">
                <svg  id="speaker-icon" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M16 9C16.5 9.5 17 10.5 17 12C17 13.5 16.5 14.5 16 15M19 6C20.5 7.5 21 10 21 12C21 14 20.5 16.5 19 18M13 3L7 8H5C3.89543 8 3 8.89543 3 10V14C3 15.1046 3.89543 16 5 16H7L13 21V3Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
                <svg id="mute-icon"  width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
                    <path d="M10.6 5L13 3V8M3 3L21 21M13 18V21L7 16H5C3.89543 16 3 15.1046 3 14V10C3 9.63571 3.09739 9.29417 3.26756 9" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
            </button>
      <span class="wrap"><input type="range" id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="speed-menu">⋮</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <button class="speed-option" data-speed="0.5">0.5x</button>
        <button class="speed-option" data-speed="1">1x</button>
        <button class="speed-option" data-speed="1.5">1.5x</button>
        <button class="speed-option" data-speed="2">2x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



EDIT:
Here's a pure CSS approach (workaround):


audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
  display: none;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

/*essential part for the cover: */
.wrap::before {
  content: '';
  background: #f3f3f3;
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 42px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*to hide the cover in Firefox: */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .wrap::before {
    content: none;
  }
}
<div class="wrap"><audio controls="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg"></audio>
  <div>



This covers the "/" with the matching background color of the background it stands on.

Thank you for taking your time to answer, if JS is the only way to do it, I'd rather stick with the buggy "/".
The problem, which I specified in the question, has multiple audios, a lot of them. Using JS will imply a heavy performance hit, which I don't want to deal with: There are 7 events for each audio element, now think about 70 audios, there will be a lot of subscribed events. In my application, I have a convo. I was avoiding using JS to access the shadow DOM in chrome and manually remove the "/", which should be a bit lighter than custom elements

also please refrain from using var, it creates scope bugs which might be very hard to debug

I specified in the question I wanted to deal with it in CSS/ Using shadow dom and native pseudo selectors, I think might be more beneficial a solution that uses it (I.e. Someone Googles how to create pseudo selectors in native elements)

@OverclockedSkid I've updated my answer. Please, take a look.

Awesome @irogu , it did work and indeed was a great trick, thank you :)
I'll update the question to fit better (it didn't need the pseudo element thing)

Ah @iorgu , I see what you did, it is a small cover for it, it works for my use case, as I'm using it Chromium-only to create a PDF using playwright. In firefox it looks a bit buggy, but it does the work anyways

@OverclockedSkid lol, yes, as I wrote: it's a workaround. Though I tested it in Firefox and the cover should not appear there... I'm glad I could help, and you're very welcome.
